# "Main Method not Public" - Error message when trying to run program on Eclipse

Tags: java, class, program-entry-point

Here's the code I'm using on Eclipse I don't understand where I've gone wrong. I'm a Java beginner so i'm not too familiar with the subject. Any help would be much appreciated. The error always eccors when i try and see how far i've gone by running the program, Ease on the computer jargon please I'm new to this lol.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.LineBorder;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeEvent;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeListener;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;

public class CBombRombot extends JFrame implements ActionListener, ChangeListener {

    private JPanel panel;
    private JPanel bottompanel;
    private JPanel rightpanel;

    private static void main(String[] args) {
        CBombRombot frame = new CBombRombot();
        frame.setTitle("CBombRobot Application");
        frame.setSize(875, 550);
        frame.show();
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    }

    private void createGUI() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        Container window = getContentPane();
        window.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(650, 450));
        panel.setBackground(Color.white);
        window.add(panel);

        rightpanel = new JPanel();
        rightpanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 180));
        rightpanel.setBackground(Color.lightGray);
        window.add(rightpanel, BorderLayout.EAST);

        bottompanel = new JPanel();
        bottompanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 50));
        bottompanel.setBackground(Color.lightGray);
        window.add(bottompanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    }

    @Override
    public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

}
```

Comment: I wish all error messages were as clear and as specific.

Comment: @NPE - You might be being a bit too subtle here :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, your main method needs to be public:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
```

Have a look at some tutorial out there, for example [this](http://www.geom.uiuc.edu/~daeron/docs/javaguide/java/nutsandbolts/main.html):

> In the Java language, when you execute a class with the Java interpreter, the runtime system starts by calling the class's main() method. The main() method then calls all the other methods required to run your application.

Or the official [Oracle tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/getStarted/application/#MAIN):

> In the Java programming language, every application must contain a main method whose signature is: `public static void main(String[] args)`

Comment: Thanks that helped but now none of the panels i've added are showing up in the program

Comment: I then suggest you to follow some swing tutorial out there.

Comment: Yeah will do there's still a countdown before i can accept the answer thanks for the help I'll look at those tutorials

Answer (score 1):

You need to declare main method as public static void. This is the reaseon:

- Public - main method is called by JVM to run the method which is
  outside the scope of project therefore the access specifier has to be
  public to permit call from anywhere outside the application
- static - When the JVM makes are call to the main method there is not
  object existing for the class being called therefore it has to have
  static method to allow invocation from class.
- void - Java is platform independant language therefore if it will
  return some value then the value may mean different to different
  platforms so unlike C it can not assume a behavior of returning value
  to the operating system.

Reference: [Why main() in java is public static void main](http://www.coderanch.com/t/411381/java/java/main-java-declared-public-static)